# Getting object using LINQ Min()?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a LINQ query that ends with .Min(mytable.Id).  This will return an integer.  I then have to do another query to pull that object from that table.  Is there a way to do this without writing two queries?

I could put the .Min() query as a subquery but is that any faster than two separate queries?

Comment: Could you please share the rest of your query to see if there are optimization opportunities? Also please tell us if this is an in-memory query, or it runs against an outside data store (LINQ2SQL, EF, etc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
.OrderBy(m => m.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

should do it without any additional dependencies.

Since its deferred, this will be pretty quick.

Comment: It's inefficient (`O(n log n)`), you don't need to sort the collection to get the min... it can be done in `O(n)` with a method like MinBy (see my answer)

Comment: It won't completely sort the collection. `OrderBy` is deferred.

Comment: It's deferred in the sense that it won't start sorting until the first item is requested, but once it starts sorting the collection, it will sort it completely (that's what the .NET implementation does anyway; [Jon Skeet's Edulinq implementation](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/07/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-26d-fixing-the-key-selectors-and-yielding-early.aspx) is better in this regard, as it will start yielding items before the sort is complete)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque It's also deferred in the sense that it won't be dealt with by the query provider until the last call. The OP mentioning tables suggests it could be EF or Linq2SQL, in which case it will be turned into the equivalent of `select top 1 * from table order by id`, which in turn will be implemented by the database in different ways depending on the the indexing but could well be O(n log n), O(n) or O(1) depending on a variety of things. In any case MinBy is O(n) but after its retrieved every row, and hence much less efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Use `OrderBy` clause, then take 1st item.